# How to include the umbraco_client folder when publishing with Web Deploy?

Tags: msbuild, umbraco, webdeploy

When installing Umbraco as a NuGet package only the umbraco folder is included into the Visual Studio project, but not the umbraco_client folder. The reason for this is that the contents of the umbraco_client folder shouldn't be referenced from Visual Studio. But when publishing the website with Web Deploy I need to have the umbraco_client folder deployed.

One solution is to include the umbraco_client folder into the VS project. The downside to this solution is that upgrading Umbraco via NuGet gets annoying and error prone. You have to remember to exclude and re-include the umbraco_client folder into the project.

So is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following MSBuild script to the .csproj file.

```
<Project>
...
   <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
                        CustomCollectFiles;
                        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
                </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles"]]>
    <ItemGroup>
      <_umbraco_client_files Include="umbraco_client\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_umbraco_client_files.Identity)"]]>
        <DestinationRelativePath>umbraco_client\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>

    </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

If you want to automate the process of adding the above code into all new Umbraco projects you can create your own NuGet package. Firstly have Umbraco as a dependency. Then add a Build folder and then a .targets file. In the .targets file you add the above code.

For details on the MSBuild script see this article: http://blog.samstephens.co.nz/2010-10-18/msbuild-including-extra-files-multiple-builds/